# How to create output file using command line?

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command

I'm using this command to remove all duplicate lines:

```
sort file.txt | uniq -u
```

But it just displays all the unique lines in terminal.  What do I need to change to make it create a new file named newfile.txt that all the unique lines are in?

Answer (score 3):

just redirect to a file

> sort file.txt | uniq -u > newfile.txt